# XAMPP - Access denied for user 'michael'@'localhost' (using password: YES). Using a php file to connect to the MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I am getting this error when I try to use a php login page to connect to the database. I have both `apache` and `MySQL` running. My apache is listening on port `8080`. I have created a user "michael" with password "17701788" with privileges to all databases using the phpmyadmin interface. I have tried changing the `conf.ini` file of `phpmyadmin` but it still didnt work.

This is my `dbconnect.php` file

```
<?php
$dbConn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'michael', '17701788', 'autoservice');
if(!$dbConn) {
    die("Failed to connect to database " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: check hostname of MySQL user "michael".

Answer (score -1):

Check the hostname. You might wanna try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Its the same thing but sometimes things get funny. if this does not work. delete the current created user and create another. this time;
1. be sure not to copy and paste the password especially as it could have white spaces.
2. Enter each credential carefully.

run and lets see.

When the coffee gets finished, stress makes us not see very tiny errors. lol